# Escape @ character in a Regex

Tags: c#, html, regex, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm using 1000hz bootstrap validator to validate an email input and I can't get to escape the '@' character in my regular expression`&#64;`. Does anyone has an idea?

I tried @@, @('@') or even hexadecimal code (@). The hexadecimal was working fine until I updated Google Chrome to V53 and now it isn't valid anymore

Here's my input:

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_%+-]+&#64;[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}" required data-error="Enter a valid email address" name="contractor-email" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. smith.mike@smith.com" />
```

Additionally, Chrome throws the following error message: validator.min.js:94 Pattern attribute value ^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4} is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/: Invalid escape

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to "escape" it? `@` is not a special character. Doesn't `pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}"` work? You can even write it as `pattern="[\w.%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}"` since some escaping is redundant and `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` = `\w`. Also, the pattern is anchored by default

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the '@' is a special character in razor C# mvc, hence the need to escape it

Comment: Then try replacing it with `\\x40` or `\\u0040`. Not sure about the double escape ``\``, maybe single one will do. Check both.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried all four options and none worked.

Comment: Check other parts of the code. That might be related to validator.min.js. Try other patterns. If simple ones do not work there might be other issues than just at sign.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried a simple regex (^\S+&#64;\S+$) and it worked so I think the issue comes from the regex

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is the best practice, but use @("@") works

Comment: I tried it before and while it works with most browsers, it doesn't work with Chrome V53

Comment: It's weird, I'm using the version 53.0.2785.116 and for me it works

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the error wasn't from the '@' symbol but about the way I escaped the characters in the first element of my regex. The following regex works: `^[a-zA-Z0-9%+-\._]+&#64;[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}`.

Thanks for the ones who helped.